# How would you render backface culling with Eevee engine?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm using backface culling to make contours but it will not render with Eevee. The first image is with the hand in the view.

[image]
The second image is when I attempt to render.

[image]

I was thinking of using nodes to enable it but I am open to other ideas. The only solutions I found were either outdated or only cover Cycles.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to do it on a material level, using nodes. There is no way to activate backface culling on final render.

Comment: It was fixed a while ago. now just activate the backface culling on the material properties window.

Comment: For anyone wondering you have to do this : 
1 For evee, you have to enable the backface culling option on the materials options,  and you have to set the Blend Mode and Shadow Mode to Alpha Clip or Alpha Hashed. and change the shader like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160930/make-invisible-depending-on-point-of-view?noredirect=1&lq=1

2 If you want on Cycles. Just change the shaders.