# make invisible depending on point of view

Tags: transparency

suppose I have modelled a room like that:
[image]

when I look at it from outside like in screenshot, I want the walls whose normals are not going towards my point of view to go transparent. In other words, I want to see the insides of the room so that the walls at which I am looking from outside, go transparent. see the screenshot for illustration, I have just hidden those faces

[image]

when I change my point of view, other faces have to go transparent while others become visible.

I think that must be somewhere on the surface but as always my Google skills are too bad to find out

Comment: Do you want the object to be affected by this in the solid, or rendered shading?

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 basically, I don't care. I would prefer solid, Eevee would be good as well. but not Cycles because then I couldn't work fast enough with that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the room's normals point inwards, you can accomplish this by using the *Geometry* node, a *Mix Shader* and a *Transparent BSDF*.

Connect the *Backfacing* socket of the *Geometry* node to the *Fac* socket of the *Mix Shader* node. Next connect your actual material nodes to the upper *Shader* input of the *Mix Shader* node and the *Transparent BSDF* to the lower one.

This effectively creates a backface culling material.

If you're using Eevee, you will also have to set the *Blend Mode* and *Shadow Mode* to *Alpha Clip* or *Alpha Hashed*. In case you're only using Eevee and don't need a material for Cycles, you can enable the *Backface Culling* option (above the *Blend Mode*) instead of using the node setup.

Don't forget to add lights inside the room.

[image: Shader]

[image: Eevee Blend Modes]

---

If you only want this for the viewport, then you can enable *Backface Culling* in the *Viewport Shading* options.

[image: Viewport Shading]

Comment: ..I get very curious shadowing effects with my set-up, if I light a room the right-way-out.. but not if i turn it inside out, and flip the mix. I'd love to know why..

Comment: @RobinBetts I've made a mistake in the first version. *Alpha Blend* shouldn't be used in combination with *Show Backface*. It's essentially an ordering issue which also broke the screen space reflection. Setting the *Blend Mode* and *Shadow Mode* to *Alpha Hashed* works well.

Answer (score 5):

You can set up a shader to be transparent if evaluated for a camera ray which is backfacing.

[image]

Curiously, in EEVEE, I found it worked better  with the normals facing *outwards* from the room (eliminating front-facing, rather than back-facing faces, as shown). In the material, both transparency and shadows are set to alpha-hashed.

[image]
[image]