# Building sets and the "fourth wall"

Tags: modeling, camera

I'm currently experimenting with building a simple set (a room with a bed, nightstand, etc) with the idea of using it to generate backgrounds for a 2D art project.  I hate drawing backgrounds and I'm quite enjoying getting to grips with Blender.  :)

I've run into an issue with this though, in that the "room" is basically a big cube inside of which I'm putting the furniture.  It's also quite a small room so in order to create the shots I want the camera has to be "outside" the room.

[image]

I'm aware that in reality TV sets are built with 3 walls so that the camera can be placed where the action is to be shot from (hence "fourth wall" to refer to the audience) and I figured that'd be easy enough to do and indeed it is, but doing so involves deleting a face from the room cube.

[image]

If I want to move the camera somewhere else then that face needs to be put back and a different face needs to be deleted.  Complicating this is the fact that at some point the room will need windows, a door, etc, and there will be posters, pictures and other decorative items hung on the walls.  It'd be easy to delete a wall with those kinds of details and forget to replace it (or lose it in the undo buffer)

I thought of making each wall an object in its own right and hiding them, but this only hides them from the viewport.  They reappear in the render.

I considered making a transparent material and applying it to the wall I want to shoot the scene through.

[image]

This worked fairly well... except that I'm also using Freestyle to create a hand-drawn effect, and apparently the big cube in the way prevents Freestyle from applying line effects to anything behind it, even if the face I'm viewing through is invisible.

[image]

There has to be a simple way of managing this.  If so, what is it?  How to I create a room with walls (and other items) I can non-destructively remove from the scene so I can view the interior, without deleting the walls entirely?

I'm using Blender 2.81a. with Eevee serving as the render engine.

Comment: Related: [How can I make a material only apply to a side of a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane)

Comment: Also related: [Hiding the front walls of a room](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/160930/35559)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make each wall as a separate object.
Then just disable/enable them in the Viewport and Render

*Use the toggles for Viewport/Render visibility*

[image]

*I know this is such a basic answer... but I've already built the walls...*

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Oof, glad to be of help :). I was going to delete it, figuring you probably considered this. Good luck with your project :).

Comment: I'm pretty much a newbie to this (I've made the Blender Guru doughnut and run through a few other tutorials but this project is more or less my first project not directly based on a tutorial)