# Blender rendering black screen when light out of interior

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

I'm pretty new to blender and for starting wanted to create my room. I just wanted to make render in middle of work to see how is it look like without noise and all that laggy stuff.

I started it and all I see is black screen(on preview it works fine). Render takes a while, so at start I thought that final result will show something else but still(rendered in cycles but EEVEE shows the same).

After some research and trying some stuff nothing helped. So I tried to put light inside of room and it worked, but light shouldn't be there.

[Blend file](https://dropmefiles.com/JOLuH)

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, now i know the reason of this.
Thing that caused it is boolean modifier and cubes which I used to do this blocked any light no matter hiden it or not.

My solution was to make them invisible for render in visibility tab [image: Uchecked this box]

Comment: Hi :). You can also use [outliner toggles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165242/) to hide objects from render :).